# Beginner Question: "No terminal defined for 'i' at line 2 col 1 int "i" 10" Lark

Tags: python, python-3.x, parsing, lark-parser

I am very new to lark and am trying to create a simple parser, but I am getting suck on a seemingly simple quesion, why does "No terminal defined for 'i' at line 2 col 1 int "i" 10" show up? Here is my grammar:

```
start: set_str
     | set_int

COMMENT: ";" /[^\n]/*

set_str: "str " STRING " " STRING
set_int: "int " STRING " " NUMBER

%import common.ESCAPED_STRING -> STRING
%import common.SIGNED_NUMBER  -> NUMBER
%ignore COMMENT
%ignore " "
%ignore "\n"
```

and the text input:

```
int "i" 10 ; this is a comment
str "s" "test"
```

I am new and do not know why this is not working, any tips would be available

also, just a smaller second question is there a way to get rid of the quotes around "i" and "s", because when I remove them they do not become escaped strings anymore.

Comment: What is the output you are getting and what is the one you are expecting?

Comment: I am getting the error and expecting:

int

  - i

  - 10

str

  - s

  "test"

Comment: How about adding this information to the question?

Comment: The error messages appears since you only expect a single line, not multiple. you have to change your start rule to repeat what it does, as example with an `*`. And for your question `common` defines another terminal `CNAME` which is probably what you want for names.

Comment: Ah ok, how would I use `*`?

Comment: After I while of trying to use it, it only gives this error now: `Expecting: {'__ANON_0'}`

Comment: @Z3R0 I would suggest trying to learn a bit more about ebnf.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you read the full error message, you see that the only expected Token is `<END-OF-FILE>`. This means that there is more input than your grammar consumes. I assume what you want is for `start` to be parsed as often as possible. This is achieved via an operator in ebnf, with `*` meaning 'repeat zero or more times' and `+` meaning 'repeat one or more times'. Therefore to fix your grammar:

```
start: (set_str | set_int)+

COMMENT: ";" /[^\n]/*

set_str: "str" NAME STRING
set_int: "int" NAME NUMBER

%import common.ESCAPED_STRING -> STRING
%import common.CNAME-> NAME
%import common.SIGNED_NUMBER  -> NUMBER
%ignore COMMENT
%ignore " "
%ignore "\n"
```

Also note that I made a few other changes: I replaced the first `STRING` in the `set_*` with the also from `common` imported `NAME`. This is what I assume you want for your second question.

I also removed the `" "` in the `set_*`. Since you `%ignore` them, it isn't required, and it might cause problems in the future.